# Android Application with twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

I am implementing an application which has twitter integration in it.I referred the link
https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample for implementation.But the problem is that when i run the program and  click the tweet button logcat shows error
"Error during OAuth retrieve request token".
Please guide me.

Comment: set the current date and time in your device and try once

Comment: but the date and time settings in my emulator are disabled.cant be accessed.But they are correct.wat to do now?

Comment: uncheck "Automatic date&time" after then only u r able to change the date and time

Comment: I set the date and time.But no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Twitter4j

[Github link](https://github.com/twitter/twitter4j)

This link has examples too

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app you are compiling has network permissions enabled.

Take a look at my approach using Twitter4j. It uses only a single, small source code [file](https://github.com/RobertSzkutak/AndroidExamples/blob/master/TwitterExample/src/com/robertszkutak/androidexamples/twitterexample/AndroidTwitterExample.java). https://github.com/RobertSzkutak/AndroidExamples/tree/master/TwitterExample

Comment: i tried the example given in ur link.but the same error is coming.

Comment: It's GPL software... if I want to use it in my own apps or in other people's commercial apps, I need to publish all the source code for those apps. Kiss of death as far as getting people to use it in their apps and as far as building a community that contributes improvements.

Answer (score 0):

check below link

http://yarakambharathi.blogspot.in/2012/05/twitter-integration-in-android-first.html?